# Rearrange displays using powershell

Tags: powershell, screen, multiple-monitors

I have a machine with two screens. For some reason my windows doesn't keep the configuration when I rearrange the display on Windows display settings.

Actually my displays are listed as

```
!-------!!-------!
!       !!       !
!   2   !!   1   !
!       !!       !
!-------!!-------!
```

and I would like to have then as

```
!-------!!-------!
!       !!       !
!   1   !!   2   !
!       !!       !
!-------!!-------!
```

This powershell code return to me the display properties:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens

BitsPerPixel : 32
Bounds       : {X=0,Y=0,Width=1920,Height=1080}
DeviceName   : \\.\DISPLAY4
Primary      : True
WorkingArea  : {X=0,Y=0,Width=1920,Height=1040}

BitsPerPixel : 32
Bounds       : {X=-1920,Y=0,Width=1920,Height=1080}
DeviceName   : \\.\DISPLAY5
Primary      : False
WorkingArea  : {X=-1920,Y=0,Width=1920,Height=1040}
```

Wondering if there is any way, in powershell, to set the WorkingArea and Bounds properties for the seconds display.

I need that to go from

```
Bounds       : {X=-1920,Y=0,Width=1920,Height=1080}
WorkingArea  : {X=-1920,Y=0,Width=1920,Height=1040}
```

To

```
Bounds       : {X=1920,Y=0,Width=1920,Height=1080}
WorkingArea  : {X=1920,Y=0,Width=1920,Height=1040}
```

If I have a code that could this I can run the code automatically when I login into the PC and I I will automate this daily and tedious task of rearrange my displays.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Perhaps you could use [Multi_Monitor_Tool](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html)

Comment: I wish.. but I'm in a controlled environment where I can't install any third-party software. I have Windows 10 1809 and the embedded Powershell installed. Nothing more than that... that's why I'm trying to solve this using Powershell...